# Empty string when query for VACHAR data type in MySQL using Spring JdbcTemplate and Spring Data JPA

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I've been getting this strange problem with MySQL VARCHAR data type.
I have this database table in MySQL, there are two fields of VARCHAR data type,let's call these field First_name and last_name. Problem is, when querying for these particular fields using Spring JdbcTemplate or using Spring Data JpaRepository interface, it always return an empty string or white spaces even though these fields have values.
I also tried to update the values into numeric like 12345 for both fields and alter the data type into INT and had the JdbcTemplate to queryForInt and it's giving me the correct result.

Here's the Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_user")
public class AppUser extends BaseEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1008862792657260298L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 30, nullable = false)
    String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", length = 30)
    String lastName;
}
```

The code used for testing:

```
        //code #1
        JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(ds);

        String sql = "select first_name from tb_user where id=3";
        JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
        try {
            System.out.println(jt.queryForObject(sql, String.class)); //returns empty string/white space instead of actual value, e.g: JOHN

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
        }

        //code #2
        String sql = "select first_name, last_name from tb_user where id=3";
        JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
        try {
            jt.query(sql, new RowMapper<UserDTO>(){

                @Override
                public UserDTO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("first_name") + " " + rs.getString("last_name")); //also returns empty string/white spaces
                    return null;
                }

            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
        }
```

Please advice. Thank you.

-Ipie-

Comment: Would be good to show some code

Comment: Hi @Matt my apology, I have included the code I'm using. Thanks.